# Git deploy branch to server on commit/push

Tags: git, deployment, development-environment, git-branch

I'm working on a website and have started using version control (Git) and have a couple of branches ("master" and "develop" for now). So I commit frequently to "develop" and push it to Bitbucket.

What I would like is for our development web-server to always have the latest version of what's in the "develop" branch, rather than manually uploading via FTP.

I do have full access to this web-server, Windows 2008 R2 (but may be able to use Linux if needed), so can install anything I need.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I'm fairly new to Git so please say if what I want to do is just plain crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the post-receive hook on the remote git repository to catch a commit made to the development branch and make it deploy (or whatever you want) the branch.

The post-receive hook will be run on the remote whenever a push is made.  You basically need to detect whether or not the push was made to the develop branch, if it is then checkout the develop branch into your deployment directory.

My post-receive looks something like this:

```
DEPLOYDIR=/directory/you/want/to/deploy/to
BRANCH=develop
while read oldrev newrev ref; do
  if [[ $ref =~ .*/$BRANCH$ ]]; then
    echo "Ref $ref received.  Deploying branch to $DEPLOYDIR"
    cd $DEPLOYDIR
    git fetch origin
    git reset --hard origin/$BRANCH
  fi
done
```

I found this article very useful when setting up my post-receive: http://gitolite.com/deploy.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this may help but one thing I don't quite get is, how does it know this is a post-receive hook? I can't see anything in the above code that specifies this?

Comment: The "post-receive" hook script is just the name of the custom script that is run automatically from git when a push to the remote server is launched.  This feature is built into git itself.  Here's a link that describes it a little better: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Ok, maybe I should rephrase. How does Git know to run the script only for a post-receive and not, say a pre-commit or whatever?
In the Git documentation all I can see is it says to put a file in the hooks directory that is named appropriately (whatever that's supposed to mean).

Comment: A hook will only run when certain actions are performed.  post-receive is a server side hook and it will only be executed when a push is done to the server.  To enable the post-receive hook, just create a script in $GIT_DIR/hooks/post-receive and it will automateically be run whenever a push is made.